# How can I return a range of values using two drop down parameters in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I understand that in order to use drop down parameters in SSRS, a second data set is required.

Here is my main, original query:

```
--DECLARE @BegSP VARCHAR = 'JC-A'
--DECLARE @EndSP VARCHAR = 'LK-F'

SELECT DISTINCT co.cust_num,
    custaddr.name,
    co.order_date,
    coitem.due_date,
    co.Uf_Slsman5,
    co.price,
    co.co_num,
    co.datefld AS Cncl_Date,
    CASE 
        WHEN co.credit_hold = 0
            THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
        END AS Credit_Hold
FROM co,
     custaddr,
     coitem
WHERE co.cust_num = custaddr.cust_num
    AND co.cust_seq = custaddr.cust_seq
    AND co.co_num = coitem.co_num
    AND co.Uf_Slsman5 BETWEEN @BegSP AND @EndSP  
    AND coitem.stat = 'O'
ORDER BY 7 ASC
```

This allows me to view a range of SalesPerson numbers by typing the numbers in, however this is not what I want to do.

Obviously, I can't have Declared parameters in that query, because that would negate using an additional query to get the drop-down lists I'm wanting, so I took my declarations out to get this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT co.cust_num,
    custaddr.name,
    co.order_date,
    coitem.due_date,
    co.Uf_Slsman5,
    co.price,
    co.co_num,
    co.datefld AS Cncl_Date,
    CASE 
        WHEN co.credit_hold = 0
            THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
        END AS Credit_Hold
FROM co,
     custaddr,
     coitem
WHERE co.cust_num = custaddr.cust_num
    AND co.cust_seq = custaddr.cust_seq
    AND co.co_num = coitem.co_num
    AND coitem.stat = 'O'
ORDER BY 7 ASC
```

Ideally, I would like to have two drop down parameter boxes that allow me to return a range of SalesPerson numbers (co.Uf_Slsman5)

This is the second query I would normally use to provide a drop down parameter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT co.Uf_Slsman5 
FROM co
ORDER BY Uf_Slsman5
```

Herein lies my problem: This query only provides ONE drop down list and only returns ONE SalesPerson number. What can I add/fix to be able to use two drop-down lists, returning a range of SalesPerson numbers?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can either make it a Multi-select parameter OR add another parameter with another similar dataset. And treat them as RangeStart and RangeEnd. In case of the 2 parameters, you can add the first parameter to the second dataset making them cascading parameters and filter for Id > @parameterRangeStart. Hope it was clear enough

Comment: I ended up just creating a Multi-Select parameter because it's less of a headache and produced the same results I was wanting. Thank you for the suggestions